# What is the medical definition of death?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, death

What is the medical definition of *death*? And how do medical examiners determine whether a person has really deceased, as opposed to for example a condition like brain death?

Comment: I think is mainly opinion based. Even medically there are different definitions  or versions of death ([cardiopulmonary death and brain death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_death#Medical_declaration)).

Comment: Your question has been asked in a similar form before. Check out this thread: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43554/metabolic-activity-postmortem/43556#43556 - you might find a useful answer there. Full disclosure: top answer is mine.

Comment: You might be better asking how we define and determine death.

Comment: To rephrase @John's comment, you might be better asking "What are the most common ways we define death?"

Comment: From the deleted answer of Kawin M came [this link to Quora](https://www.quora.com/According-to-the-theory-of-evolution-why-do-we-die)

Answer (score -2):

Ok. So when a doctor declares a person dead, it is when their heart or brain is totally not working, and won't start working no matter what they do.

This is legal death.

If your heart stops cold, you are clinically dead. This is reversible, if you are lucky. This definition basically only exists so people can say they "died". It has no real biological significance, except for the fact that your heart is not pumping blood and providing you with oxygen. This will cause...

Biological death:
Within 5-10 minutes at room temp you have reached the event horizon of biological death. Biological death is real death.

Once this time threshold is crossed, there is almost always no going back.
This is because Cells in the brain are destroyed by oncosis, and other mechanisms and forces far beyond me.

Comment: Can you add your sources?

Comment: @AliceD I mean, it's kind of common knowledge.